# Xamarin.Forms button does not work in scrollview (iOS)

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, scrollview, landscape, orientation-changes

I created a page with a grid in Xamarin.Forms. Now I am trying to adjust it for landscape as well. The problem is, that I need to use a scrollview for the portrait mode and disable the scrollview for landscape mode. I [found a solution in my other post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183335/how-to-use-a-grid-in-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms#latest), which works good for android, but for iOS the buttons aren't clickable. Is there an other possibility to disable the scrollview for landscape? Or how can I make the buttons clickable for iOS? I posted my code already in [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183335/how-to-use-a-grid-in-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms#latest). Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I removed my old solution and I defined each row like this:

```
 mainLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = height / 8 });
```

Now each row have the perfect height and scrolling is disabled for landscape. (I divided it with eight, because I use eight rows now)